# What is the definition of the gd css unit?

Tags: css

I came across the `gd` css unit while exploring the different ways to define an element height.

Example

```
.heading{
    height: 6gd;   
}
```

Does anyone know what this is/where I can find more information on this? I don't need it for anything specific - just exploring different options that are available.

Comment: Came across where? Do you have any reason to think it isn't a mistake by the author of wherever you came across it?

Comment: @Quentin it's an available option when using `ctrl` + `spacebar` in Rider.

Comment: A new one on me! I found just one reference, in a paper over 5 years old. Does it still exist in the standard?

Comment: A _very_ transiently defined length unit for use with East-Asian languages.